# How to change layout_marginTop value of an element in a ConstraintLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I have the following ContstraintLayout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/txt_string"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/three"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/four"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_dim"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What I want is to change the marginTop value in code:

This is what I have but I have not found any method to set Top margin:

```
    AppCompatTextView mytext;

private void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

        mytext = findViewById(R.id.my_text);

//here I would like to make something like :
// mytext.setTopMargin(Xdp);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try the following code..

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.setMargins(0,10,0,0);
mytext.setLayoutParams(params);
```

`setMargin` represents following coordinates

```
setMargin(left,top,right,bottom);
```

Comment: not working, makes the text dissappear

Comment: try now, I have updated answer. if still issue arrives or not?